# Display inline causing element to be pushed further down

Tags: html, css

If you look at my codepen here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LHBqs

and change the "`display: block`" on img to "`display: inline`", it causes the text "Fine dining in a casual environment" to be pushed further down.

The "Fine dining" element below it is `h2`, which is a block element, so why does it make a difference whether or not the `img` tag is block or inline since a block element cannot show up on the same line as an inline element anyways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to margin collapsing - your `img` and the `h2` below it have margins that "touch" each other, but for block elements margins collapse (merge into one), while for inline elements they do not and they both apply, hence the additional space.

Check this article - http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing